# Android SDK does not find JDK

Tags: android, sdk, java

I am installing the Android sdk using the installer_r20.0.1-windows(setup file) for windows 7 64 bit system. Alongside i am installing jdk for it using this jdk-7u5-windows-x64(setup file) for windows. I  installed the jdk and tried going back and forth so that the sdk recognizes the jdk but it is not doing so. Please suggest me what should i do? Also if there is any issue of 32 bit and 64 bit installation please tell me...

Comment: Are you able to open Eclipse ???

Comment: There *is* a bitness issue, but I can't remember which way round it is. If it helps, I have the 32 *and* 64 bit JDKs installed and it works OK for me...

Comment: JDKs are installed to help Eclipse, just tell me this, are you able to open eclipse successfully. Where exactly are you facing the Problem, Installing the SDK into Eclipse or Starting the Eclipse

Comment: yes i am able to open the Eclipse. What jdk should i download from the java website. Please suggest

Comment: i m facing problems installing the android sdk. it need the jdk which it is not recognizing though i have installed it.

Comment: You have not installed the ADT

Answer (score 5):

Here's my experience. I installed jdk-7u9-windows-x64 and then attempted to install Android SDK (installer_r21-windows). It responds with:

> Error: Failed to find Java version for 'C:\Windows\system32\java.exe': [2] The system cannot find the file specified.

Two solutions worked for me:

1) Create an environment variable of `JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09"` using your actual path if it varies.

2) Modify the Path environment variable so that it includes the bin folder of JDK installation. The caveat here is that it needs to be before "%SystemRoot%\system32"

i.e. PATH ≈

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;`
```

instead of:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin`
```

I'm not sure if option 2 goes against the principles of the public jre vs the jdk private jre, so in general I recommend using option 1 and adding the bin directory of your jdk to the **end** of your path env variable.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had trouble installing the SDK without having JDK v6 installed, though I still (now) use JDK v7 for Eclipse and my dev environment.

See if this works for you:
Install JDKv6, then run SDK installer. It should (hopefully) detect the JDK installation and continue.
After installation, uninstall JDKv6 and now install JDKv7 and continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

Andoid sdk isn't compatible with jdk 7, you should use the latest version of jdk 6, 32 bit.

Comment: @VenomVendor Dima is correct. [Google points out that JDK 6 is required.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) It might work with JDK 7 (I'm using OpenJDK 7 64-bit on Linux) but the Android installer just works when JDK 6 32-bit is installed.

Comment: @nkr [It](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) Actually represents the minimum system requirements, I am using JDK7 and there is no other versions of JDK installed in my system, and it always [recommended to uninstall old version](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/remove_olderversions.xml) before installing the new one. so obviously JDK7 will support Eclipse without JDK6.

Comment: As from the Questioner Comments, he is not able to find the Android Tab in eclipse, When Eclipse opens, it means that JDK has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the JDK first (v7, x64), then Android SDK told me that it can not find JDK. Then I deleted C:\Windows\System32\java.exe (actually I renamed to exjava.exe) and restarted Android install and worked fine. I hope it helps, good luck.